Set Azure sensitivity label for Outlook email using vba
it seems you can set a workbook's Azure Information Protection Sensitivity label using this method:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/excel-articles/change-sensitivity-label-programatically.66/
Function SetSensitivityLabel(WB As Workbook, LblName As String)

  Dim myLabelInfo As Office.LabelInfo
  Dim Context As Variant
  Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
  Dim CurLabelID As String
  
  Dim sPublic As String
  Dim sGeneral As String
  
  Set objWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
  Set myLabelInfo = objWorkbook.SensitivityLabel.CreateLabelInfo()
  Set Context = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  
  sPublic = "788c8a80-3a15-4016-b4c2-fc99999bfa99"
  sGeneral = ""
  
  Select Case LblName
    Case "General"
      CurLabelID = sGeneral
    Case "Public"
      CurLabelID = sPublic
      
  End Select
 
  With myLabelInfo
   .AssignmentMethod = MsoAssignmentMethod.PRIVILEGED     '1
   .ContentBits = 4
   .IsEnabled = True
   .Justification = "Because"                             'Make this whatever you want
   .LabelId = CurLabelID
   .LabelName = LblName
   .SetDate = Now()
  End With

  objWorkbook.SensitivityLabel.SetLabel myLabelInfo, Context

End Function

However, I'd like to do this for an Outlook MailItem created via VBA - not a workbook. Changing objWorkbook to an Outlook MailItem in the Function above doesn't expose SensitivityLabel.CreateLabelInfo(). Is there any other way to do this? Looking at this other thread (Azure classification using vba), some answers use a draft template, some use SendKeys - both are suboptimal and answers quite old.
Is there any equivalent for Outlook that doesn't employ these methods?

Sensitivity Labels are not exposed in the Outlook Object Model.

Honoured you've replied Dmitry! Is there another way around it through a third party library like Outlook Redemption?

Sensitivity Labels are on the Redemption to do list, but there is nothing yet. If you need to apply labels on the outgoing messages, you can try to look at the properties set when you apply the label manually and set the same properties programmatically using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty. You can see the properties in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button).

Thanks Dmitry. I'm currently unable to use OutlookSpy as it's blocked by our admin. Would using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty  not trigger the Outlook Object Model Guard?

No, it would not.

Thanks for all your help @DmitryStreblechenko...the solution I've posted below works. Only issue is it currently triggers the Outlook Object Model Guard at the MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty line. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong....is there a way to avoid it?

Hmmm... Do you see the prompt for all properties or just that one? Outlook won't display security prompts if your local machine has an up-to-date version of an AV app installed.

Just the line Set PropAccessor = MailItem.PropertyAccessor is enough to trigger it. AV is up to date, but I suspect there may be something else at play. Is there another way to avoid triggering it?

It doesn't appear any other time e.g. when creating an email, setting the To Field, Body, displaying it etc. Not sure why that line alone would trigger it

Setting any properties does not trigger it, only reading some of them. Are you sure it is a security prompt? Does it say "A program is trying to..."?

Correct. That's the exact box. I split the code up and it seems even just accessing the PropertyAccessor causes this. The dialog gets shown on the line Set PropAccessor = MailItem.PropertyAccessor Perhaps I'm setting up my Outlook object wrong? I posted my solution as the answer below and whilst debugging, the security dialog appears on that the line. Is there something I'm doing wrong in the set up that's causing this?

Do yo see the prompt if you read the To property?

Apologies I misread your question. Correct - it seems reading any properties generates this security box

That means AV app is either not installed or is out of date.

Hmm...it's a work PC in a big enterprise, AV says it's up to date and under "Programmatic Access" in Outlook it says "Antivirus status: Valid"...is there anything else it could be?

Is there any other way to set this property without using the PropertyAccessor?

You can use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (I am its author).

Is there a way to do it using UserProperties.Add or perhaps ItemProperties.Add ? As these don't seem to generate a security box

No, these methods cannot be used with arbitrary MAPI properties.

I finally found a solution that works! Thanks @DmitryStreblechenko. for all the help.
See code below:
Public Sub CreateEmailWithSensitivityLabel()
                        
    Dim OutlookApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim MailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim dateTimeNow As String
    Dim MSIPLabel As String
    
    Set MailItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    Const SensitivityLabelGUID As String = "XXXXX"
    Const SiteGUID As String = "XXXXX"
    
    dateTimeNow = Format(Date, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
    
    MSIPLabel = "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_Enabled=true;" & _
                "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_Method=Privileged;" & _
                "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_Name=" & SensitivityLabelGUID & ";" & _
                "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_SetDate=" & dateTimeNow & "; " & _
                "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_SiteId=" & SiteGUID & "; "
    
    Dim PropAccessor As PropertyAccessor
    Set PropAccessor = MailItem.PropertyAccessor
    
    PropAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/msip_labels", MSIPLabel
    
    MailItem.Display

    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set MailItem = Nothing
    Set PropAccessor = Nothing

End Sub

If you don't know your required Label ID and Site ID:
All you need to do is find out your label ID and your site ID which will be specific to your organisation. This can be found by running the following code which will print the MSIP Label headers to your immediate window:
Public Sub RetrieveMSIPLabelsFromExistingEmailsInInbox()

    Dim i As Integer
    
    Dim OutlookApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim MailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim folderInQuestion As Outlook.Folder
    Dim OutlookItems As Outlook.Items

    Set folderInQuestion = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    Set OutlookItems = folderInQuestion.Items
    
    OutlookItems.Sort "SentOn", True
    
    If Not folderInQuestion Is Nothing Then
        
        For i = 1 To 10
        
            Set MailItem = OutlookItems.Item(i)
            
            Debug.Print MailItem.Subject
            Debug.Print MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/msip_labels/0x0000001F")
            
        Next i
        
    End If
    
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set MailItem = Nothing
    Set folderInQuestion = Nothing
    Set OutlookItems = Nothing
  
End Sub


Based on the question and answer from @EC99 here and the comments from @DmitryStreblechenko I came up with 3 approaches to create outlook-emails from excel-vba - I think the original question pointed to the creation of outlook-emails from excel-vba. The answer from @EC99 includes outlook-vba code. Thank you both @EC99 and @DmitryStreblechenko: Without your question/answer/comments I could not do that.
What's important to know is that my answer and @EC99's answer copy the confidential label from another email.
Below you will find 3 approaches:
I. You found your values for SensitivityLabelGUID and SiteGUID and you just write it in your code (See answer from EC99 to find the values (values need to come from an confidential mail))
II. You want to use another email on your filesystem that has the confidential label to copy it from there
III. You want to use another email from outlook by its EntryID that has the confidential label to copy it from there
'Option 1 (You found your values for SensitivityLabelGUID and SiteGUID and you just write it in your code
Sub SendMail_Option1()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Dim SensitivityLabelGUID As String
Dim SiteGUID As String
Dim PropAccessor As Variant
Set PropAccessor = OutMail.PropertyAccessor
 
SensitivityLabelGUID = "345xy691-4219-45fd-985f-fdc3a990e22c" ' <----------- Fill your values here
SiteGUID = "1ad0323a-54x2-49a6-9e49-52tz0a954c89" ' <----------- Fill your values here


MSIPLabel = "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_Enabled=true;" & _
            "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_Method=Privileged;" & _
            "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_Name=" & SensitivityLabelGUID & ";" & _
            "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_SetDate=" & dateTimeNow & "; " & _
            "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_SiteId=" & SiteGUID & "; "

PropAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/msip_labels", MSIPLabel

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    With OutMail
        .To = "test@test.test"
        .CC = "test@test.test"
        '.BCC = "test@test.test"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .HTMLBody = "Test"
        .Sensitivity = 3 '2=Private 3=Confidential
        .Display '.Send
   End With

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
End Sub

   'Option 2 (You want to use another email on your filesystem that has the confidential label to copy it from there)
   Sub SendMail_Option2()
   Dim OutApp As Object
   Dim OutMail As Object
   Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
   Dim MailTemplatePath As String
   Dim MailTemplate As Object
   Dim MailTemplatePropertyAccessor As String
   Dim SensitivityLabelGUID As String
   Dim SiteGUID As String
   Dim PropAccessor As Variant
   Set PropAccessor = OutMail.PropertyAccessor
   
   MailTemplatePath = "C:\Confidential_Email_As_Sample.msg" '<----------- Fill your value here
   Set MailTemplate = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(MailTemplatePath)
   MailTemplatePropertyAccessor = MailTemplate.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/msip_labels/0x0000001F")
   SensitivityLabelGUID = Mid(MailTemplatePropertyAccessor, InStr(MailTemplatePropertyAccessor, "MSIP_Label_") + Len("MSIP_Label_"), 36)
   SiteGUID = Mid(MailTemplatePropertyAccessor, InStr(MailTemplatePropertyAccessor, "SiteId=") + Len("SiteId="), 36)
   
   MSIPLabel = "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_Enabled=true;" & _
               "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_Method=Privileged;" & _
               "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_Name=" & SensitivityLabelGUID & ";" & _
               "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_SetDate=" & dateTimeNow & "; " & _
               "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_SiteId=" & SiteGUID & "; "
   
   PropAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/msip_labels", MSIPLabel
   
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
       With OutMail
           .To = "test@test.test"
           .CC = "test@test.test"
           '.BCC = "test@test.test"
           .Subject = "Test"
           .HTMLBody = "Test"
           .Sensitivity = 3 '2=Private 3=Confidential
           .Display '.Send
      End With
   
   Exit Sub
   ErrorHandler:
   End Sub


'Option 3 (You want to use another email from outlook by its EntryID that has the confidential label to copy it from there)
Sub SendMail_Option3()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim OutSession As Object
Set OutSession = OutApp.Session
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Dim MailTemplateEntryID As String

Dim MailTemplatePropertyAccessor As String
Dim SensitivityLabelGUID As String
Dim SiteGUID As String
Dim PropAccessor As Variant
Set PropAccessor = OutMail.PropertyAccessor

MailTemplateEntryID = "0000000055A868E9D99D704E94D6609666E5366B78002211D0E2E0384A41B06DC02781D89DF10012004F9X6F00009DAC56FE5596124D92023CA476945FD40001231EF4F01230" '<----------- Fill your value here
Set MailTemplate = OutSession.GetItemFromID(MailTemplateEntryID) 'Get the email item by EntryID
MailTemplatePropertyAccessor = MailTemplate.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/msip_labels/0x0000001F")
SensitivityLabelGUID = Mid(MailTemplatePropertyAccessor, InStr(MailTemplatePropertyAccessor, "MSIP_Label_") + Len("MSIP_Label_"), 36)
SiteGUID = Mid(MailTemplatePropertyAccessor, InStr(MailTemplatePropertyAccessor, "SiteId=") + Len("SiteId="), 36)

MSIPLabel = "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_Enabled=true;" & _
            "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_Method=Privileged;" & _
            "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_Name=" & SensitivityLabelGUID & ";" & _
            "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_SetDate=" & dateTimeNow & "; " & _
            "MSIP_Label_" & SensitivityLabelGUID & "_SiteId=" & SiteGUID & "; "

PropAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/msip_labels", MSIPLabel

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    With OutMail
        .To = "test@test.test"
        .CC = "test@test.test"
        '.BCC = "test@test.test"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .HTMLBody = "Test"
        .Sensitivity = 3 '2=Private 3=Confidential
        .Display '.Send
   End With

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
End Sub

