Add label sensitivity to the e-mail in Outlook while sending the mails using Python
I’m trying to send multiple emails using Python script and I want to add label to the e-mail defined as “Confidential”.
def send_email(reciepient, email, sender, subject, body, att):
     mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
     mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = sender
     mail.To = email
     mail.CC = sender
     mail.Subject = subject
     mail.HtmlBody = body
     mail.Attachments.Add(att)
     mail.Display(False)
     mail.send

How to update my code and define the label in the e-mail?
I’m looking for the advise on how to update my code and define default label for my emails.

What exactly is outlook here? What library / API wrapper are you using?

I'm using the following libraries:
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd
import io
from tqdm import tqdm
and Outlook version is 1.2024.725.400 (Production) -> New Outlook Client Desktop
Label PurView Sensitivity Labels

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78724792/set-azure-sensitivity-label-for-outlook-email-using-vba
